# Docker: confused about multiple containers

Tags: docker

I would like to be able to replicate a development environment across several computers. I thought that Docker could be a good tool to do it, but I got stuck.

I have an app which uses:

- apache with some extensions
- PHP FPM
- MySQL
- Composer
- Compass (to recompile SASS files)
- Grunt & Bower

All the files should stay on the host machine, and be made available to the services.

So I created a Dockerfile, which configures and starts Apache. Great!

Unfortunately I just can't figure out how to proceed from here.

How can I configure PHP FPM, MySQL and Compass? I understand that I shoud run each of those process in a separate container, and link them together (as opposed to start several services inside the same container).

Instinctively, I would create several Dockerfiles, one for each service, and then start each one with docker-compose. But this looks like is not the way to go, and I could not figure out what the correct idea is.

I found a lot of custom images, but I would strongly prefer to create personally every container with my own configuration. Is this possible?

Or am I better off just provisioning and running a full VM, in Vagrant or directly on VirtualBox??

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you thinking docker-compose is not the correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

Docker Compose has always been a great tool in such scenario where you have small microservices instead of one large monolithic application dumped into a single Docker Image. If you don't want to have large number of Dockerfile, you can always build up your own Docker Image with necessary packaging to make it simple.

Example: Instead of pulling official Ubuntu Docker Image, you can build up your own Ubuntu Docker Image with necessary packaging. This will reduce your confusion around having large number of Dockerfile. But be aware that this will carry overhead of building new Docker Image everytime you want to make any changes and something which is not recommended for development environment.

Here is the snippet of the docker-compose.yml file from [this](https://github.com/ajeetraina/docker-nginx-php-mysql) link which is very simple to understand, doesn't hold individual Dockerfile and can be easily customize based on your requirement:

```
 version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
            - "./etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template"
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
            - "3000:443"
        environment:
            - NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST}
        command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysqldb
    php:
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
    composer:
        image: "composer"
        volumes:
            - "./web/app:/app"
        command: install
    myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysqldb
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql
        container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "8989:3306"
        volumes:
            - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track.  [Docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is what you want.

Each "service" would either be a Docker image or a local Dockerfile that gets built.  You can specify different file paths and file names in your compose file to make things easier.  Then use Docker links to tie all the containers together.